# How to pass a variable (a database row) into a while loop function

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using a simple PHP script to display links in my footer. These links and anchor text are in my database. I have no problem displaying the links and anchor text with the code I am using. Here is an example of how my code looks when it's functioning.

Using PHP/MySQL how can I pull a value from my database down into my website and inside the while loop comparison?

Small excerpt of my code:

```
            <?php
                // Change the limit in db_connect.
                $link_counter = 0;
                while ($link_counter < $counter_query_result[1]['counter_value']; ){
                    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
                    $link_counter++;
                }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_links_box">
          <ul>
            <?php
                while ($link_counter < $counter_query_result[2]['counter_value']; ){
                    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
                    $link_counter++;
                }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_links_box">
          <ul>
            <?php
                while ($link_counter < $counter_query_result[3]['counter_value']; ){
                    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
                    $link_counter++;
                }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_links_box">
          <ul>
            <?php
                while ($link_counter < $counter_query_result[4]['counter_value']; ){
                    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
                    $link_counter++;
                }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_links_box">
          <ul>
            <?php
                while ($link_counter < $counter_query_result[5]['counter_value']; ){
                    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
                    $link_counter++;
                }
            ?>


                    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
                    $link_counter++;
                }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_links_box">
          <ul>
            <?php
                while ($link_counter < echo $counter_query_result[1]['counter_value_2']; ){
                    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
                    $link_counter++;
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Rather than downvote the question tell me what I can do to make the question better. This was a totally valid question as I truly encountered the issue which I was able to solve. Or did you not even bother you read the question but downvoted cause I didn't upvote your answer instead?

Comment: I don't think you can make any assumptions about who downvoted your question - it could be any one of a million users `:)`. Anyway, don't worry about it - they do happen here occasionally. If you answer some questions you'll pick up positive rep in no time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to echo it. It is already a variable to use for comparison:

```
while ($link_counter < $counter_query_result[1]['counter_value_2'] ){
    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
    $link_counter++;
 }
```

This assumes that the value of `$counter_query_result[1]['counter_value_2']` is in fact an `int`

Comment: Ok It did not work for me. I edited my question above so that you can see what my code now looks like.

Comment: @user2833068 can you `var_dump($counter_query_result)` and add that to your post? I'm curious what is in it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we have 20 links and we want 5 blocks consisting of 4 links in each.

```
$links_array = array_chunk($links_array, 5);
foreach ( $links_array as $block_num => $block_links ) { ?>
<div id="footer_links_box">
    <ul>
    <?
    foreach ( $block_links as $link ) {
        echo $link;
    }
    ?>

     </ul>
</div>
<?  } ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm not looking to change the code. If i do it that way i'd have to change everything. I just need to know a single line of code. Or how to properly pulll a bit of data from a database into that position in place of the comparison value.

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question. Here is the solution. You can not put the database query/result in the while loop: (The first 6 lines of code right below here is the old code that does not work)

```
<?php
    while ($link_counter < $counter_query_result[3]['counter_value']; ){
        echo $links_array[$link_counter];
        $link_counter++;
    }
?>
```

Instead you will need to assign the statement to a variable and call that variable from within the loop. The following is a completed bit of code that did in fact work 110%. I am now using this in my completed website.

this code below is the finished code and works.

```
            <?php
                // Start Database Variable For Footer Link Counter //
                $var1 = $counter_result[1]['counter_row_value'];
                $var2 = $counter_result[2]['counter_row_value'];
                $var3 = $counter_result[3]['counter_row_value'];
                $var4 = $counter_result[4]['counter_row_value'];
                $var5 = $counter_result[5]['counter_row_value'];
                // End Database Varibale For Footer Link Counter //
                $link_counter = 0;

                while ($link_counter < $var1 ){
                    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
                    $link_counter++;
                }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_links_box">
          <ul>
            <?php
                while ($link_counter < $var2 ){
                    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
                    $link_counter++;
                }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_links_box">
          <ul>
            <?php
                while ($link_counter < $var3 ){
                    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
                    $link_counter++;
                }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_links_box">
          <ul>
            <?php
                while ($link_counter < $var4 ){
                    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
                    $link_counter++;
                }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer_links_box">
          <ul>
            <?php
                while ($link_counter < $var5 ){
                    echo $links_array[$link_counter];
                    $link_counter++;
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: This is not any different then the answer i posted. It just adds the overhead of creating 5 new variables..

Comment: if you tried your answer it does not work. Mine does. But thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @immulatin: if you are offering a "competing answer", my view tends to be that you should usually refrain from downvoting your competitors. This is because our internal biases are much more likely to find fault with other answers, since of course we usually prefer our own! That said, I agree that if your answer was broadly similar to this one, the poster here could have +1 for your efforts. (Short version: let's make this site collaborative rather than competitive) `:)`.

Comment: @halfer I completely agree, just for the record I was not the one to down vote :). I was stating for future people to look at the answers that this is probably not the best answer to look at for a solution.